# Gulp: Скопировать добавленные либо переименованные файлы при инкрементальной сборке

Tags: node.js, gulp

Приведённый ниже пресет:

- Копирует все файлы (на примере изображений) при первом запуске таска 'Copy images to build' в папку **buld**
- При изменении этих файлов `{since: gulp.lastRun('Copy images to build')})` пропустит только изменённый файл.

--

```
gulp.task('Copy images to build', () => {
    return gulp.src('source/images/**/*', {since: gulp.lastRun('Copy images to build')})
            .pipe(gulp.dest('buld/images'))
});

gulp.watch('source/images/**/*', gulp.series('Copy images to build'));
```

Однако, добавление нового файла либо переименование уже имеющегося не является изменением файла, потому при выполнении этих операций файлы скопированы не будут (`{since: gulp.lastRun('Copy images to build')}` их не пропустит). Как этого можно добиться, если перед запуском инкрементальной сборки я очищаю предыдущую сборку?

Подсказка: знаю, что в node.js есть команда `touch`, которая создаёт эффект обновления файла. Знаю, что `gulp.watch()`, он же chokidar обнаруживает добавление или переименовывание файла; осталось только как-то прописать прописать `touch` на понятном для gulp JavaScrip-е.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> знаю, что в node.js есть команда touch, которая создаёт эффект обновления файла.

Команда `touch` есть в Unix-подобных системах.

В *Nodejs* есть плагин `touch`, который работает практически так же, как *Unix* `touch`. Если вы на Unix-подобных, можно просто последовать одному из примеров, если нет то надо устанавливать *node touch*.

Вот такой камандой:

```
npm install touch
```

Поменяйте примеры, если будете использовать [nodejs touch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/touch) .

---

> Знаю, что `gulp.watch()`, он же chokidar обнаруживает добавление или
>   переименовывание файла; осталось только как-то прописать прописать
>   `touch` на понятном для gulp JavaScrip-е.

Вот такой пример для *gulp 4*:

```
'use strict';

var cp = require('child_process');
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('reset', function() {
  // In gulp 4, you can return a child process to signal task completion
  return cp.execFile('touch -d "2 hours ago" source/images/**/* ');
});
```

---

Вот такой пример с плагином *gulp-exec*:

Если не установлен плагин `gulp-exec`, то

```
npm i gulp-exec
```

Только потом

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var exec = require('gulp-exec');

gulp.task('reset', function() {
  return gulp.src('./**/**')
    .pipe(exec('touch -d "2 hours ago" source/images/**/*'));
});
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ!