# NodeJS, не копируются файлы (fs.copyFile(): operation not permitted)

Tags: node.js, gulp

Пытаясь самостоятельно решить проблему из моего другого вопроса ([Gulp: Скопировать добавленные либо переименованные файлы при инкрементальной сборке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/851682/gulp-%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B1%D0%BE)), я решил копировать добавленные или переименованные файлы средствами Node.js, то есть без использования gulp:

```
gulp.task('Watch source files', () => {

    let imagesWatcher = gulp.watch('src/images/**/*.*');

    imagesWatcher.on('add', file => {

        // error
        fs.copyFile(file, 'dist/images', error => { if (error) throw error;}); 
    });
});
```

К сожалению, не вышло из-за следующей ошибки:

```
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, copyfile `...` -> `...`
```

Поскольку моя ОС - Windows, то так нет таких проблем с правами доступа, как в UNIX-подобных системах. Потому непонятно, почему это нельзя копировать...

Comment: Вы, случайно, не `fs-extra` пользуетесь?

Comment: @Дмытрык, Если `fs-extra` - отдельный от `fs` модуль, то нет. У меня импортирован стандартный `fs`: `fs = require('fs')`;

Comment: попробуйте указать путь записи  с именем файла. "you should indicate the full path with the filename in the destination parameter." - https://github.com/nhnent/tui.jsdoc-template/issues/29

Comment: как успехи, получилось?

Comment: @Дмытрык, Будем считать, что да:) Вашу рекомендацию я обязательно учту на будущее, но конкретно в моём коде больше подошло [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/856546/193415) решение. Спасибо Вам за ответ в комментарии!

Answer (score 2):

`fs.copyFile` разве умеет директории копировать? Нужно либо [node-fs-extra](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra) использовать, либо [ncp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ncp).